# How can I split a variable in two like [x, y] = X in Scilab?

Tags: scilab

The syntax `[x, y] = X`, assigning `X(1)` to `x` and `X(2)` to `y`, is definitely possible in Scilab, for example:

```
[p, q] = cdfnor("PQ", 0, 0, 1)
```

But if I try it, I get an "incompatible assignation" error:

```
a = [0, 1]
[x, y] = a
Incompatible assignation: trying to assign 1 values in 2 variables.
```

How can I replicate this behavior in my own code?

Answer (score 4):

Scilab has tuple assignments such as `[x, y] = (0, 1)`. This is somewhat close to what you want, but this parentheses syntax does not appear to correspond to any Scilab data structure (I tried this with a *[list](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/list.html)*, unsuccessfully).

So it appears that one needs a function with a variable number of output variables ([varargout](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/varargout.html)), which takes a vector and returns a list of variables. There appears to be no built-in way to convert a vector to a list, so I used a loop. The function is named `deal` because of the similarity to [Matlab's `deal` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).

```
function varargout = deal(a)
    varargout = list()
    for i = 1:length(a)
        varargout(i) = a(i)
    end
endfunction

a = [0, 1]
[x, y] = deal(a)
```